# Allowing for short positions in parametric portfolio

Tags: r, constraints, portfolio

I have to optimize a parametric portfolio where the weights depend on state variables. Suppose that I have the following return matrix (`ret`)

```
[0.5 0.1 0.2 0.2
 0.4 0.1 0.9 0.1
 0.6 0.2 0.8 0.7]
```

To construct the parametrix portfolio, I have to multiply `ret` with the "conditional" weights matrix. The weight of each asset depend on 2 dependent variables `A` and `B`:

```
w1=as.vector(((x[1]*A)+(x[2]*B)))
w2=as.vector(((x[1]*A)+(x[2]*B))) 
w3=as.vector(((x[1]*A)+(x[2]*B)))
w4=as.vector(((x[1]*A)+(x[2]*B)))
```

.... # 2 constraints related to `w1` , `w2` , `w3` , `w4`

The, the weight matrix is contructed as following:

```
  w=cbind(w1,w2,w3,w4)
```

Finally, by Combining return and weight vectors, we get the return matrix

```
  r=w*ret
```

And then, the portfolio, 
`portfolio<-rowSums(r)`

The problem is, before calculating r, I need to add 2 constraints:

- Weights sum to one
- allowing for short positions.

For example, I have to get the following w matrix

```
[0.25 -0.25  0.5  0.5
 0.3  -0.25  0.6 -0.35
 0.4  -0.4   0.6  0.4 ]
```

This is the modified code

```
charact<-cbind(A,B)
func<-function(x,ret,charact) {    #x: parameters (x1 and x2)
  w1=as.vector(((x[1]*A)+(x[2]*B))) #the weight of each asset depends on 2 charac A and B
  w2=as.vector(((x[1]*A)+(x[2]*B))) 
  w3=as.vector(((x[1]*A)+(x[2]*B)))
  w4=as.vector(((x[1]*A)+(x[2]*B)))
  w=cbind(w1,w2,w3,w4)
  # Weight vector should sum to one
  pen=sum(abs(rowSums(w) - c(1,1,1) )) *10
  r=w*ret

  #Calculating utility
  u<-1/nrow(r)*sum((1+rp)^(1-5)/(1-5))
  obj<--u+pen
  return(obj)
}
```

Comment: What's the difficulty ....  short position weights have a negative sign? Can you construct a small annotated example of the sort of matrix structure you expect as input and the desired output?

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: I'm still unclear about exactly what those weight parameters refer to but it appears my hypothesis that negative weights are involved has some support. One method of implementing a constraint is to penalize departures from it. You can multiply `sum(abs(rowSums(w) - c(1,1,1) ))` by suitable large number and add it to your objective function that is then minimized, (or in the case where your function is maximized you would subtract.)

Comment: It doesn't work .. I tried as u told me but no avail .. I get equally weights that their sum differ in each row.

Comment: "Doesn't work". Sadder (and less informative) words were never written. I cannot suggest anything because you have not include code that demonstrates what you attempted in following my suggestion. You never even referenced a package or a function with which you were attempting the optimization, and you certainly showed no code.